# I tried running this, and it said "int object is not subscriptable" on line 16

Tags: python

Program for an ISBN code checker

```
code=str(input("Please enter the ISBN code. "))
incode=0
modul=0
sumcode=0
subt=0
count=0
multvar=1
codelist2=[]
if len(code)!=13:
    print("Invalid ISBN code.")
elif code.isdigit() and len(code)==13:
    codelist=list(code)
    code=int(code)
    for i in range (12):
        if multvar==1:
            codelist.append(code[count]*1)  # This is where the Python Shell says there is an error
            multvar+=1
            count+=1
        elif multvar==2:
            codelist.append(code[count]*3)
            multvar-=1
            count+=1
    sumcode=sum(codelist)
    modul=sumcode%10
    subt=10-modul
    if subt==codelist[12]:
        print("Valid ISBN code.")
    else:
        print("Invalid ISBN code.")
```

I have been trying to fix this for a while, and nobody I know has been able to help me fix the error

Comment: You can only use `[]` notation with lists and other iterable objects. Not with integers. What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: `code = int(code)` and then `code[count]*1` makes no sense.  First what are you trying to get at with count?  If it is the exact digit, change code to `str'  Second why are you multiplying anything by 1???????

Answer (score 0):

I have almost managed to make it work

```
code=str(input("Enter an ISBN code to check if it's valid. Please make sure you add spaces between each number. "))
incode=0
modul=0
sumcode=0
subt=0
count=0
multvar=1
codelist=code.split()
while True:
    codelist[count]=int(codelist[count])
    count+=1
    if count==13:
        break
if len(code)!=13:
    count=0
    print("Invalid ISBN code.")
elif code.isdigit() and len(code)==13:
    for i in range (12):
        if multvar==1:
            codelist.append(code[count])
            multvar+=1
            count+=1
        elif multvar==2:
            codelist.append(code[count]*3)
            multvar-=1
            count+=1
        sumcode=sum(codelist)
        modul=sumcode%10
        subt=10-modul
        if subt==codelist[12]:
            print("Valid ISBN code.")
        else:
            print("Invalid ISBN code.")
```

Comment: This looks like it's supposed to be an edit to your question, not an answer.